# How can you make an armor that when you wear it, it will give you resistance 255?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So with the `/effect` command, it can give either you or a random entity in Minecraft. However, you can actually make custom items in the game with effects when you wear it, here:

So I want to make armor with resistance 255 so it would make you immortal, and pls put the command that you need to have armor with a custom nametag so the effect you appear and that's by using the "tag" command, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `tag` command could be used but then the item needs to be placed on the ground to apply the tag to the item, it's better to directly apply a tag to the item with the `Tags:[""]` parameter.

By using this command:

```
execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:
[{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",tag:
{Tags:["Immortal"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Immortal Chestplate\"}"}}}]}] 
run effect give @s resistance 1 255
```

You will give all players that wear a chest plate named `Immortal Chestplate` and if the chest plate has the tag `Immortal`, resistance 255 for 1 sec. This will only affect any player that actually has the correct item, i.e. the name and the tag needs to match.

Place this in a command block with `Repeat` `Unconditional` `Always Active`.

This command will place an immortal chestplate on a player(in the chest slot):

```
/replaceitem entity @p armor.chest minecraft:iron_chestplate{Tags:["Immortal"],
display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Immortal Chestplate\"}"}}
```

Then with the `give` command:

```
/give @p iron_chestplate{Tags:["Immortal"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Immortal Chestplate\"}"}}
```

Using the `summon` command:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1,tag:
{Tags:["Immortal"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Immortal Chestplate\"}"}}}}
```

If you want to test for a helmet you change the number at `Slot:102b` to `103:b`, leggings for `101b`, and boots for `100b`.

**Note**

`replaceitem` will be replaced with the `item` command in 1.17, the difference is that you need to add `replace` before the item:

```
/replaceitem entity @p armor.chest iron_chestplate{}
```

becomes

```
/item entity @p armor.chest replace iron_chestplate{}
```